# How do I wrap a text in a cell of a longtable

Tags: longtable

Please could you help me to format this table in a way that I can wrap the text properly and fit the table within an A4 page. I used tablesgenerator.com but it is not perfect in terms of formatting. You can see an image showing the type of format I would like to achieve. Also, I expect the table to be presented in landscape and span across multiple pages

[image: Table I need to be created in latex]

Many thanks in advance for anyone who can fix my code. I have spent ages trying to fix this with no success

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.10\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.10\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.09\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.106\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.096\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.15\linewidth}
} 

\toprule
This is   the first title of this table               & This is the   second title of this table                                  & This is the   third title of this table                             & This is the   fourth title of this table & This is the   ffth title of this table                                             & This is the   sixth title of this table            & This is the   seventh title of this table          & This is the   eighth title of this table                                                                                        \\* \midrule
\endfirsthead

            \multicolumn{8}{l}%
            {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- (Continued from previous page)}} \tabularnewline
%
\toprule
This is   the first title of this table               & This is the   second title of this table                                  & This is the   third title of this table                             & This is the   fourth title of this table & This is the   ffth title of this table                                             & This is the   sixth title of this table            & This is the   seventh title of this table          & This is the   eighth title of this table                                                                                        \\* \midrule

\endhead
%
        
            %&     & \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            \multicolumn{8}{l}{{(Continued on next page)}} \tabularnewline
            \endfoot
            
            \hline
            \endlastfoot

\multicolumn{8}{l}{Primary endpoint XXXXX}                                                                              \\* \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{author1, year}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{Quality   of life instrument 233454}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{Utility   index global scale}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{OR   (95\%CI) (from xyz regression) {[}N{]}}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{p\textgreater{}0.10   for all visits-specific comparisons; p=0.534 for overall comparison}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 1}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 2}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 3}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{author2, year}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{Quality   of life instrument 233454}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{Utility   index global scale}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{OR   (95\%CI) (from xyz regression) {[}N{]}}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{p\textgreater{}0.10   for all visits-specific comparisons; p=0.534 for overall comparison}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 1}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823) {[}NR{]}}                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 2}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 3}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823) {[}NR{]}}                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{12}{*}{author3, year}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{12}{*}{FACT}}                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}{*}{Utility   index global scale1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{12}{*}{OR   (95\%CI) (from xyz regression) {[}N{]}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}{*}{p\textgreater{}0.10   for all visits-specific comparisons; p=0.534 for overall comparison}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){6-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}{*}{Utility index global scale2}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}{*}{p\textgreater{}0.10   for all visits-specific comparisons; p=0.534 for overall comparison}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5 week}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{author4, year}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{Quality   of life instrument 233454}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{Utility   index global scale}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0}                   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{OR   (95\%CI) (from xyz regression) {[}N{]}}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{p\textgreater{}0.10   for all visits-specific comparisons; p=0.534 for overall comparison}} \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 1}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823) {[}NR{]}}                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 2}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.849(0.803,0.893)   {[}NR{]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Week 3}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823) {[}NR{]}}                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                                                                           \\* \midrule
\\* \bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why on earth is every single cell wrapped in a \multicolumn{.}{c}{...}` construct. That completely defeats/overrdies the `m` column type choices. In particular, no line wrapping will occur in `c`-type cells.

Comment: Please could you amend my code and show me how I should improve the code?

Comment: If you want clean and understandable code,  do not use table generators. `& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &` is exactly the same that  `& &`, the  `{[}NR{]}` is the same that `[NR]` ... and as said, in other cases is not only superfluous, but harmful. My advice is make the  table manually and  use `\multicolumn` only when you really  need a multicolumn cell (as far I see, only in 10 cells of the picture).

Comment: So **that** is where all those useless `\hspace{0pt}` come from!  I thought it was just a bad template.

Comment: Please help me to improve this table because I am a complete beginner, Once I have a template I can work around it. Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, table generators are still not able to generate decent tables for all but the most simple and trivial cases. (And, in such cases, one probably doesn't need the help of a table generator to begin with, right?) Anyway, for the case shown in the OP's query, pretty much every single thing that could go wrong, in terms of output of a table generator's run, has gone wrong, to the point of unusability. For instance, by encasing virtually every single cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrapper, the code has made sure that no automatic line wrapping can occur.

Unfortunately, not only is the output of the table generator utility essentially unusable, the table's design also raises a few questions. I've tried to apply some vigorous clean-up to the code, but I'm not sure I understand the table's design. (For sure, it doesn't help that the header cells are devoid of information.) AFAICT, the main information is contained in columns 4, 6, and 7. Questions: Why aren't these columns placed together? Put differently, wouldn't it be better to exchange the order of columns 4 and 5?

Anyway, the following code may help you get started toward a fully usable table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,pdflscape,longtable,array,ragged2e}
   % note: 'multirow' package is no longer used

%% Define two new column types:
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1\linewidth}}
%% Create two handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\mytabc[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} c @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mytabcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{%
     \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} c@{\hspace{12pt}}c @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next two instructions
\footnotesize % switch to 10pt font
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{longtable}{@{} L{0.08} L{0.08} L{0.10} C{0.09} 
                      L{0.11} C{0.15} C{0.15} L{0.16} @{}} 

%% headers and footers:
\caption{This is the table caption}\\
\toprule
Source & % I've tried to come up with more meaningful labels
Quality of life instrument  & 
This is the third title of this table  & 
This is the fourth title of this table [N] & 
This is the fifth title of this table  & 
This is the sixth title of this table  [NR] & 
This is the seventh title of this table [NR] & 
$p$-values \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{{\bfseries\tablename\ \thetable}, 
   continued from previous page} \\
\addlinespace
\toprule
Source  & 
Quality of life instrument  & 
This is the third title of this table  & 
This is the fourth title of this table [N] & 
This is the fifth title of this table  & 
This is the sixth title of this table [NR] & 
This is the seventh title of this table [NR] & 
$p$-values \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(Continued on next page)} \\
\endfoot
  
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table:
\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{Primary endpoint XXXXX} \\ 
\midrule
author1, year & 233454 & Utility index global scale & 
  \mytabc{%
     0\\ 
     Week 1\\ 
     Week 2\\ 
     Week 3} & 
  OR (95\%CI) (from xyz regression) & 
  \mytabcc{%
     0.762 (0.703,0.823) & 0.849 (0.803,0.893) \\
     0.762 (0.703,0.823) & 0.849 (0.803,0.893) \\
     0.762 (0.703,0.823) & 0.849 (0.803,0.893) \\
     0.762 (0.703,0.823) & 0.849 (0.803,0.893)} &
  $p>0.10$ for all visit-specific comparisons; 
  $p=0.534$ for overall comparison \\ 
\midrule
author2, year & 233454 & Utility index global scale & 
  \mytabc{%
     0\\ 
     Week 1\\ 
     Week 2\\ 
     Week 3} & 
  OR (95\%CI) (from xyz regression) & 
  \mytabcc{%
     0.762 (0.703,0.823) & 0.849 (0.803,0.893) \\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)} \\
     0.762 (0.703,0.823) & 0.849 (0.803,0.893)\\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.762(0.703,0.823)}} &
  $p>0.10$ for all visit-specific comparisons; 
  $p=0.534$ for overall comparison \\ 
%\midrule

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I will look at your code and adapt it to my problem and I will let you know if I managed to fix the table

Comment: HI I get this error "Missing number, treated as zero.

 
‪tables/1_2_systreview_2/tabletemp_4.tex, 16‬
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.16 \begin
           {longtable}{@{} L{0.08} L{0.08} L{0.10} C{0.09}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'."

Comment: I run your code as a standalone code and it works but it does not work when I insert it in the context of my compiled files

Comment: @Xavier - Did you copy the `\newcolumntype` directives for the `L` and `C` column types into your production file?

Comment: I did copy \newcolumntype directives for the L and C but it does not work

Comment: @Xavier - Sorry, but a statement such as "it does not work" is not actionable; it certainly provides no basis for any kind of diagnostic checking. Sadly, but probably not surpisingly, my psychic divination powers are simply rubbish. Could you see fit to elaborate on what "it does not work" actually entails? Alternatively, do you maybe want me to delete this answer, since it evidently is of no use to you? Please advise.